# Stylus inline SVG data uri without base64 encoding

Tags: css, node.js, svg, stylus, data-uri

How can I embed a SVG data uri in CSS using [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) preprocessor without the SVG being Base64 encoded?

Like this:

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>[...]</svg>');
```

instead of this:

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwg[...]');
```

Normaly I've used `stylus.url()` to embed images, but it will also Base64 encode SVGs.

I want to use data uris instead of external files to save file requests. And I've realised that Base64 encoding SVGs actually adds bytes instead of reducing size.

I can't find a method to embed the SVG as-is.

Comment: You can't do an externat .svg file and call it in css ?
Like background: url(youshape.svg);

Comment: Also, background images (even SVG) are **not** "inline images".

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm used to SASS and Compass where the method is literally called `inline-image()`, so that's what confused me. What would you call it? "embed"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I couldn't find a established way to do this I had to solve it myself. I wrote a simple node module that wraps `stylus.url()` but replaces how SVGs are inlined.

Link to the module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus-inline-svg

Except for some checks it basically does this:

```
found = stylus.utils.lookup(url.string, options.paths);

if(!found) return literal;

buf = fs.readFileSync(found);

buf = String(buf)
    .replace(/<\?xml(.+?)\?>/, '')
    .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');

return new stylus.nodes.Literal("url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + buf + "')");
```

Answer (score 5):

Stylus now has this functionality built in:

http://stylus-lang.com/docs/functions.url.html

The `embedurl` function with `utf8` support was added in version `0.54.0` on March 5th 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Literal:

```
@css {
   .svg {
      background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwg[...]');
   }
}
```

Compiling to:

```
   .svg {
      background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwg[...]');
   }
```